# Map jquery function objects and pass them to template events instance function

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a dozen of events like this one inside a `Template.instance_name.events()` function :

```js
'click .bname1': function(e, i) {
  $('.course').show()
  $('.course').not('.name1').hide();
},
'click .bname2': function(e, i) {
  $('.course').show()
  $('.course').not('.name2').hide();
}, ...
```

i wish to use an array of names ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', ...]  to create events objects

I tried the following, creation an o = {} empty object, and in a map function of my names creating event objects like this:

```js
o['click .b' + name] = function (e, i) {
  $('.course').show()
  $('.course').not('.' + name).hide();
}
```

But when i pass the o object to my events function it's not working.

edit:

### The problem was coming not from the map function but from the call to the database.

The map is created in the Template.templatename.onCreated function
using a call to db.

```
var arr =  db.find({type: 'course'}).fetch();
```

but it seems the fetching of the results is unconsistent with non persistent results:
either empty array `main.js:41 []`
or complete

```
main.js:41 (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

then the map doesnt work when there is no result in the array.
And dont know how to solve this.
I tried with `this.autorun` but the results are still unconsistent.

Comment: Silly question, shouldn't it be `o['click .b' + name]` (with a `b`)?

Comment: Can you please Show the map function, too and a console print of the result object, before it's passed to the Template's events function?